# Fastest way to go from linear index to grid index

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm interested in going from a position in a vector to the index in the grid version of the vector with given strides, for example, say I have the vector:

```
vec = {58, 94, 19, 68, 54, 77, 1, 18, 49, 20, 90, 44, 91, 89, 15, 0, 
   60, 18, 19, 44, 87, 5, 8, 42, 51, 55, 87, 71, 83, 68, 53, 58, 27, 
   17, 8, 14, 33, 58, 86, 3, 91, 66, 3, 16, 98, 84, 72, 98, 9, 30, 90,
    99, 15, 0, 82, 76, 86, 58, 77, 58};
```

And say I have strides `{5, 4, 3}`, the position `35` in the vector would correspond to the index `{3, 4, 2}`:

```
vec[[35]]

4

ArrayReshape[vec, {5, 4, 3}][[3, 4, 2]]

4
```

How can I get this index fast and in a vectorized fashion because I will have potentially many positions to extract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not intended to be competitive but fun for me to write.

```
unrank[d : {__Integer}][n_Integer] :=
   ⌊ 1 + d*Mod[(n - 1)/Reverse@FoldList[Times, Reverse@d], 1] ⌋

unrank[{5, 4, 3}][35]

SeedRandom[0]
r = RandomInteger[{2, 99}, 20];

unrank[r][1*^30]
```

> ```
> {3, 4, 2}
>
> {2, 8, 6, 6, 40, 38, 5, 51, 16, 12, 15, 34, 8, 45, 5, 28, 31, 12, 9, 8}
> ```

---

This time aiming for better performance specifically for application to lists of indexes.

```
unrankList[dim_List][n_List] :=
  1 + FoldList[QuotientRemainder[#[[1]], #2]\[Transpose] &, {n - 1}, 
     Reverse@dim][[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1, 2]]\[Transpose]

SeedRandom[0]
r = RandomInteger[{2, 99}, 20];
x = RandomInteger[{1, 1*^30}, 100];

unrankList[r][x]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00119, Null}
> ```

---

Here is a derivative of your own method that seems to be a bit faster on my machine. Like your code it uses machine precision so it will become incorrect with very large indexes.

```
unrank3[n_Integer, d_] := unrank3[{n}, d]

unrank3[n_List, dim : {__Integer}] :=
  With[{tl = N@Reverse@FoldList[Divide, 1, Reverse@Rest@dim]},
    1 + Mod[⌊Partition[tl, 1].{n - 1}⌋, dim]\[Transpose]
  ]
```

Comment: Nice refactoring. I’m gonna leave this open maybe another day but then I’ll run all the tests and accept this if no one comes up with something faster. This answer certainly covers the most bases.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you.  I posted a bit prematurely and had to make a couple of code edits after the fact.  Please let me know if you find any failings with the current version.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is what you want:

```
IntegerDigits[35 - 1, MixedRadix[{5, 4, 3}], 3] + 1
```

In general:

```
gridIndex[n_Integer, shape_List] := 
 IntegerDigits[n - 1, MixedRadix[shape], Length@shape] + 1
```

Comment: @C.E. You're right, it just needs dimension length specification

Comment: This is a very nice solution, +1

Comment: Do you know what version is required to run this code?  In v10.1 I get `{1 + IntegerDigits[34, MixedRadix[5], 3], 1 + IntegerDigits[34, MixedRadix[4], 3], 
 1 + IntegerDigits[34, MixedRadix[3], 3]}`

Comment: This is clean but surprisingly incredibly slow...

Answer (score 12):

If you have enough memory, then a lookup table may be fastest:

```
shape = {5, 4, 3};
indices = Tuples[Range /@ shape];
```

Lookup is fast:

```
indices[[35]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.*10^-7, {3, 4, 2}} *)
```

Also, it seems that doing lots of lookups simultaneously is even faster (per lookup):

```
indices[[{22, 45, 35, 49, 36, 9, 9, 39, 59, 14}]] // RepeatedTiming
```

Comment: I don't and would need to construct it on the fly each time, but it is a clever simple work around.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the obligatory compiled version; it is not as fast as Roman's lookup method but it is also less memory hungry (in particular if indexing is supposed to be done into `SparseArray` whose dense version does not fit into memory).

A compiled helper function:

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {mods, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{r = n - 1, d, m},
    Table[
     m = Compile`GetElement[mods, i];
     d = Quotient[r, m];
     r = r - d m;
     d + 1,
     {i, 1, Length[mods]}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
getInds[idx_, shape_] :=
 cf[idx, Reverse[Most[FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse[shape]]]]]
```

Usage example and timing test, comparing against swish's and Roman's proposals:

```
RandomSeed[123];
shape = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4];
idx = RandomInteger[{1, Times @@ shape}, 10000];

a = gridIndex[#, shape] & /@ idx; // RepeatedTiming // First

b = getInds[idx, shape]; // RepeatedTiming // First

indices = Tuples[Range /@ shape];
c = indices[[idx]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.429
>
> 0.00059
>
> 0.0000700
>
> True

Comment: What do you mean? It leads to the same results as the other methods...

Comment: Erm. I am getting 3D indices for `shape = {5, 4, 3}`...

Comment: Ah, that's because the second argument of `cf` should be `Reverse[Most[FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse[shape]]]]` (which has to be computed only once; that's why I did not include it into `cf`).

Comment: Ah I see. I'll add a tiny function building on `cf` to make this clear since I clearly did not read enough.

Comment: One cool thing is that at least for me that uncompiled (but packed-array based) version is comparable to/faster than the compiled one but this actually switches at very large numbers of indices. Oh and then it switches back!

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit surprised that a memory bound lookup table should be faster than a few integer operations. But as long as the lookup table fits into relatively low level cache, memory boundedness does not seem to be a problem. Why it switches back in the end is a complete miracle to me though (I did not experience it so far).

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I came up with:

```
getSubindex[index_, stride_] := {
  Mod[index, stride, 1],
  Ceiling[index/stride]
  }
getIndex[index_, strides_] := 
 Reverse@FoldPairList[getSubindex, index, Reverse@strides]
```

This is comparable to swish's solution speed-wise:

```
gridIndex[1000, {3, 5, 4, 6}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000061, {3, 2, 3, 4}}

```
getIndex[1000, {3, 5, 4, 6}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000052, {3, 2, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 6):

So after I posted the question last night I came up with a solution that is fast and vectorized: (note that if you're working with huge numbers you'll need to remove the `N` for accuracy, but you'll incur a huge speed penalty)

```
gifs[inds_, strides : {__Integer}] :=
 Module[
  {
   accstr,
   stride = strides,
   ind = inds - 1,
   moddable,
   modres
   },
  accstr =
   N@
    Append[
     Reverse@FoldList[Times, strides[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]],
     1
     ];
  moddable = If[ListQ@inds, Map[ind/# &, accstr], ind/accstr];
  modres = 1 + Mod[Floor[moddable], stride];
  If[ListQ@inds, Transpose, Identity]@modres
  ]
```

Obligatory performance comparison:

```
tests = RandomInteger[{1, 60}, 100];

res = gifs[tests, {5, 4, 3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.000053

res == gridIndex[tests, {5, 4, 3}]

True

gridIndex[tests, {5, 4, 3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.0064

getIndex[tests, {5, 4, 3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00032

unrankList[{5, 4, 3}][tests]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00039

getInds[tests, {5, 4, 3}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

0.000063
```

Clearly vectorization is doing what it should and getting us the performance we'd expect (which is interestingly better than a compiled implementation on my machine)

Here's a more detailed performance analysis which shows we're long-term a little bit better than Mathematica's auto-parallelization in compiled functions:

```
RandomSeed[123];
shape = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4];
sizes = {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 75000, 
   100000, 125000, 150000, 500000};
idxs = RandomInteger[{1, Times @@ shape}, #] & /@ sizes;

testC =
  MapThread[
   {#, getInds[#2, shape]; // RepeatedTiming // First} &,
   {
    sizes,
    idxs
    }
   ];

testU =
  MapThread[
   {#, gifs[#2, shape]; // RepeatedTiming // First} &,
   {
    sizes,
    idxs
    }
   ];

ListLinePlot[
 {
  testC,
  testU
  },
 PlotLegends -> {"getInds", "gifs"},
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't agree with the output of my function, e.g. I get `{2, 8, 6, 6, 40, 38, 5, 51, 16, 12, 16, 36, 6, 33, 2, 19, 1, 13, 5, 2}` from `gifs` for the example in my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hmm...I don't know what's happening there. It seems to only happen for very large numbers for some reason, though. All my other test cases against other answers pan out just fine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah it's my use of `N` to speed things up that introduces some numerical instability for huge numbers.

Comment: Please see my `unrankList` and tell me how it performs for you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it's pretty good on my machine. Comparable to C.E.'s solution with foling `Mod` and `Ceiling`.

Comment: A refactoring of your own method, `unrank3`, seems to be a little bit faster or my machine.  Please test it.  *edit* I just updated it to eliminate a Transpose operation.